# In CouchDB, should I use the _id for relation and _changes?

Tags: couchdb, cloudant

I've been [reading a lot](https://glynnbird.com) of [best practices](https://github.com/jo/couchdb-best-practices) and how I should [embrace the _id](https://github.com/jo/couchdb-best-practices#embrace-the-document-id). To be honest, I'm getting my kind of paranoid at the repercussions I might face if I don't do this for when I start scaling up my application.

Currently I have about 50k documents per database. It's only been a few months with heavy usage. I expect this to grow A LOT. I do a lot of `.find()` Mango Queries, not much indexing; and to be honest working off a relational style document structuring.

For example:

- First get Project from ID.
- Then do a find query that:

  - grabs all `type:signature` where `project_id: X`.
  - grabs all `type:revisions` where `project_id: X`.

The reason for this is I try VERY hard not to update documents. A lot of these documents are created offline, so doing a write once workflow is very important for me to avoid conflicts.

I'm currently at a point of no return as scheduling is getting pretty intense. If I want to change the way I'm doing things now is the best time before it gets too crazy.

I'd love to hear your thoughts about using the `_id` for data structuring and what people think.

Being able to make one call with a _all_docs grab like this sounds appealing to me:

```
{
  "include_docs": true,
  "startkey": "project:{ID}",
  "endkey": "project:{ID}:\ufff0"
}
```

An example of how ONE type of my documents are set is like so:

**Main Document**

```
{
    _id: {COUCH_GENERATED_1},
    type: "project",
    ..
    .
}
```

**Signature Document**

```
{
    _id: {COUCH_GENERATED_2},
    type: "signature",
    project_id: {COUCH_GENERATED_1},
    created_at: {UNIX_TIMESTAMP}
}
```

**Change to Main Document**

```
{
    _id: {COUCH_GENERATED_3},
    type: "revision",
    project_id: {COUCH_GENERATED_1},
    created_at: {UNIX_TIMESTAMP}
    data: [{..}]
}
```

---

I was wondering whether I should do something like this:

**Main Document**: `_id: project:{kuuid_1}`

**Signature Document**: `_id: project:{kuuid_1}:signature:{kuuid_2}`

**Change to Main Document**: `_id: project:{kuuid_1}:rev:{kuuid_3}`

I'm just trying to set up my database in a way that isn't going to mess with me in the future. I know problems are going to come up but I'd like not to heavily change the structure if I can avoid it.

Another reason I am thinking of this is that I watch for `_changes` in my databases and being able to know what types are coming through without getting each document every time a document changes sound appealing also.

Answer (score 4):

Setting up your database structure so that it makes data retrieval easier *is* good practice. It seems to me you have some options:

1. If there is a field called `project_id` in the documents of interest, you can create an index on `project_id` which would allow you to fetch all documents pertaining to a known project_id cheaply. see [CouchDB Find](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.2.0/api/database/find.html)
2. Create a MapReduce index keyed on `project_id` e.g `if (doc.project_id) { emit(doc.project_id)}`. The index that this produces would allow you to fetch documents by known project_id with judicious use of `start_key`& `end_key` when querying the view. see [Introduction to views](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/ddocs/views/intro.html)
3. As you say, packing more information into the `_id` field allows you to perform range queries on the `_all_docs` endpoint.

If you choose a key design of:

```
project{project_id}:signature{kuuid}
```

then the primary index of the database has all of a single project's documents grouped together. Putting the project_id *before* the ':' character is preparation for a forthcoming CouchDB feature called "partitioned databases", which groups logically related documents in their own partition, making it quicker and easier to perform queries on a single partition, in your case a project. This feature isn't ready yet but it's likely to have a `{partition_key}:{document_key}` format for the `_id` field, so there's no harm in getting your document _ids ready for it for when it lands (see [CouchDB mailing list](https://lists.apache.org/thread.html/4d09ee0fcc4afec8f25dbd540f9c4f0af67d3fdcc41f26f36ff7a32d@%3Cdev.couchdb.apache.org%3E)! In the meantime, a range query on _all_docs will work.

Comment: Possibly relevant even if you are using CouchDB without using PouchDB: see also [`relational-pouch`](https://github.com/pouchdb-community/relational-pouch#how-does-it-work). Its source code will show something similar to the answer above, in context.